# Combining train trips in a spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

My student job entails planning the shifts of a number of surveyors who ride on selected trains and count passengers.

I would like to know if there is a way to make this task easier, probably in Excel, but other software could be an option too.

This is a short description of the task:

On a spreadsheet I have a list of the departures from the train schedule that needs to be covered by the survey. Something like this:

```
Time of departure | Station | Time of arrival | Station | Number of surveyors needed
05:36             | A       | 09:52           | B       | 3
10:10             | B       | 14:56           | A       | 2
11:23             | B       | 15:52           | C       | 1
03:01             | C       | 08:30           | A       | 2
```

The list is really long!

As it is now I make the shifts by copying the lines from one tab in Excel to another, combining them in accordance to certain criteria:

1. The individual train trips that combine to a shift should be connected.
2. The surveyors should be able to make the connections with a minimum time span of 10 min to change trains.
3. The whole shift should be of a maximum length.
4. The surveyors should end their shift at the same train station where they started.
5. I can add in trips of transportation using any train in the train schedule to get the surveyors to make connections with trains that need surveying.
6. The time where the surveyors aren't riding on a train that needs surveying (that is, when they are waiting for a train or riding for transportation) should be minimized.

Is there a way (that doesn't involve heavy programming) I can automate or semi-automate the task of combining individual train trips in accordance at least the first criterion?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "combining"? Does that just mean listing on the same sheet?

Comment: Yes, listing them after each other. The first two lines in my example could be combined by listing them after each other in a way separated from the rest. That could count as a shift though shifts can be up to 10 hours long and involve any number of individual trips.

Comment: This seems like a classic binary search tree example.  Unfortuntately, it is, as you say, "heavy programming".  Though, if you know a little about object oriented programming, it is certainly doable.

Comment: Could you give me a few pointers to get started? Could it be done in Excel? If not, what kind of IDE what be the easiest to start with ...

Comment: @N8sBug I presume you mean "doable, just not in Excel" - unless you're planning on bringing VBScript into it? Even then, it sounds like a bit of a stretch.